# linking error with update gcc from 4.6 to 4.8 (Windows MinGW)

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

My c++ library compiles fine in MinGW gcc 4.6, and I need to compile it under gcc 4.8 and the following error occured:

```
d000014.o:(.idata$5+0x0): multiple definition of `_imp___get_output_format'
d:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmsvcrt.a(lib32_libmsvcrt_a-output_format.o):output_format.c:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I just can not figure out a way to fix this . Any one got a clue?

Comment: Generally, use the same compiler for the entire project. Or at the very least, ensure you have the same header-files.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Great advice I forget that one of my library denpendency  is compiled with another version of gcc which caused the confliction when linking with msvcrt .